# Property 'toggleExpand' does not exist on type 'AccHeaderContextProps | undefined'.ts(2339)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context

when i use the `context` to share the data, I am getting an type error from typescript as `Property 'toggleExpand' does not exist on type 'AccHeaderContextProps | undefined'.ts(2339)`. But all the props i have declared already.

```
interface AccHeaderContextProps {
  expand: boolean;
  toggleExpand: () => void;
}

const AccordionContext = createContext<AccHeaderContextProps | undefined>(
  undefined
);
```

when i use it throws error:

```
function AccordionHeder(props: AccHeaderProps) {
  const { title } = props;
  const { expand, toggleExpand } = useContext(AccordionContext);//error
  return (
    <button onClick={toggleExpand}>
      {title} <span>{expand ? "-" : "+"}</span>
    </button>
  );
}
```

[Live Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/clean-reusbale-component-n8u8g9?file=/src/components/accordion/Accordion.tsx:886-1142)

Answer (score 1):

As the error mentioned `undefined` has no property of `toggleExpand` since it simply doesn't exists and is no object. You can't have   `.toggleExpand`

You can provide a *initial* object for your context with the expected values.

```js
const AccordionContext = createContext<AccHeaderContextProps>({
  expand: false,
  toggleExpand: () => console.warn("No AccordionContext")
});
```

When rendering the component you'll use the context and get the values defined in the context provider.

Comment: Yes, it works. I did the same. What is the issue to use `undefined` ? can't we use it as initial value...!?